# Recycling Jetty Http2 Client streams -- best practice?

Tags: jetty, client, http2

We have a Jetty Http2 Client constructed roughly as the example [here](https://github.com/fstab/http2-examples/blob/master/multiplexing-examples/jetty-client/src/main/java/de/consol/labs/h2c/examples/client/jetty/JettyClientExample.java).

Each request processed by the client calls `session.newStream(...)`. It appears that old streams are not GC-ed. However, we can't seem to find a good way, in the API, to either recycle them, or close them.

Should we set a very small idle timeout using `streamPromise.get().setIdleTimeout(t)`?

Should we keep the Stream object, mark it when an exchange finishes, then reuse it? In this case though, we also need to recycle the listener, which makes is stateful.

Is there a way to "close" a Stream object, or mark it for GC? Simply setting it to null doesn't seem very API-ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams that are closed *are* GCed.

`Stream`s support half closes, so in order for a stream to be closed you need to send a frame with the `end_stream` flag set, and receive a frame with the `end_stream` flag set.

If you use `HTTP2Client` directly, chances are that you're not ending the stream on your side (i.e. you send frames, but forget to set the `end_stream` flag on the last frame you send), or the server does not end the stream (which would be a server bug).

Either case, turning on DEBUG logging for category `org.eclipse.jetty.http2` on the client will tell you whether the frames have the `end_stream` flag set, and report when streams are removed - you just need to parse the possibly large-ish log files.

Comment: All our requests are `end_stream`, they are constructed like this: `HeadersFrame headersFrame = new HeadersFrame(request, null, true);`. Also, our business logic concludes in `@Override
    public void onData(Stream stream, DataFrame frame, Callback dataCallback) {if (frame.isEndStream()) { ... ` . Is the Stream considered closed at that time?

Comment: You *must* complete the data callback. If the `onData()` you show above is on the client, then yes the stream is closed and it has already been removed just before calling `onData()`.